# How to change Emacs command line color

Tags: emacs, colors

Is there a way to change the text of the command line in emacs?
I do not know, what the real name of the command line at the bottom ist, but I marked it on the picture. It is the blue text at the bottom:

[image]

Comment: The "command line" at the bottom is called the [minibuffer](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/emacs/Minibuffer.html).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The bottom part is called **minibuffer** if I recall correctly.

```
M-x customize-face
minibuffer-prompt
```

Comment: Thnx, pushing "alt+x" and typing :
"customize-face"
"minibuffer-prompt"
opened a cusomization menu, where the color of minibuffer is called "foreground color"

Answer (score 1):

Two possibilities for this one:

One: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/windows/old/faq4.html
Just scroll down until you see the part about color, in which it gives you the libraries where you can change emacs colors using RGB values.

Two: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ColorTheme
This one's definitely a lot more robust than you need, but it's basically a 'plugin' of sorts that allows you to customize literally any color in emacs, or use premade color themes.